# Moving backwards through a gif much slower than moving forwards

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, gif

I would like to be able to move through a gif frame by frame. In the example below, I use a trackbar to select which frame of a gif I want to see. For the designer I just dropped a PictureBox in the centre of the screen and stuck a TrackBar at the bottom of the screen.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace TestGifProject {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        private Image gif;
        private FrameDimension fd;

        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();

            gif = Image.FromFile("PATH\\TO\\SOME\\GIF.gif");
            // just for this quick example...
            this.Width = gif.Width + 20;
            this.Height = gif.Height + 53;

            pictureBox1.Width = gif.Width;
            pictureBox1.Height = gif.Height;

            pictureBox1.Image = gif;

            fd = new FrameDimension(gif.FrameDimensionsList[0]);

            trackBar1.SetRange(0, gif.GetFrameCount(fd) - 1);
        }

        private void trackBar1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
            gif.SelectActiveFrame(fd, trackBar1.Value);

            pictureBox1.Image = gif;
        }
    }
}
```

When you move and release the trackbar, the frame is shown correctly however it is much slower when you scroll backwards rather than forwards (probably 10x faster forwards), often long enough to make it seem like the app has crashed. Is there anything I can do to speed up backwards scrolling through a gif?

Comment: In most animated GIF, each frame except the first one contains only the difference with the previous frame. For instance, if only the top of the image changed, then the frame will only contain the data for the top of the image. The consequence is that, to read an animated GIF backward, you need to re-read it from the start at each frame, hence the dramatic slowdown

Comment: Ah right I suspected it was something to do with how a gif is stored. Doesn't sound like there's any way to speed this up short of storing a bitmap of every frame but that's mega memory usage. Thanks for the post.

Comment: @KooKiz You should make that an answer rather than a comment

Comment: you should use the scroll event.

Comment: @Muckle_ewe I'm just explaining the cause, I'm not providing a solution

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a list where you add each frame. `SelectActiveFrame()` could be resolving the correct image with a more complex logic, which could be the reason for slow action.

Create a new list to your class' root:

```
private List<Image> frames = new List<Image>();
```

Fill the list with the frame images:

```
for(int i = 0; i < gif.GetFrameCount(fd); i++)
{
   gif.SelectActiveFrame(fd, i);
   frames.Add((Image)gif.Clone());
}
```

Then use the list to set images to the `PictureBox`:

```
pictureBox1.Image = frames[trackBar1.Value];
```

I haven't tested this, but I think it should work.